# What's the JS RegExp for this specific string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a rather isolated situation in an inventory management program where our shelf locations have a specific format, which is always `Letter: Number-Letter-Number`, such as Y: 1-E-4. Most of us coworkers just type in "y1e4" and are done with it, but that obviously creates issues with inconsistent formats in a database.  Are JS RegExp's the ideal way to automatically detect and format these alphanumeric strings?  I'm slowly wrapping my head around JavaScript's Perl syntax, but what's a simple example of formatting one of these strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> spec: detect string format of either "W: D-W-D" or "WDWD" and return **"W: D-W-D"**

This function will accept any format and return undefined if it doesnt match, returns the formatted string if a match does occur.

```
function validateInventoryCode(input) {
   var regexp = /^([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\:\s*)?(\d+)-?(\w+)-?(\d+)$/
   var r = regexp.exec(input);
   if(r != null) {
      return `${r[1]}: ${r[2]}-${r[3]}-${r[4]}`;
   }
}
```

```js
var possibles = ["y1e1", "y:1e1", "Y: 1r3", "y:    32e4", "1:e3e"];

possibles.forEach(function(posssiblity) {
  console.log(`input(${posssiblity}), result(${validateInventoryCode(posssiblity)})`);
})



function validateInventoryCode(input) {
  var regexp = /^([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\:\s*)?(\d+)-?(\w+)-?(\d+)$/
  var r = regexp.exec(input);
  if (r != null) {
    return `${r[1]}: ${r[2]}-${r[3]}-${r[4]}`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question as "convert `LetterNumberLetterNumber` to `Letter: Number-Letter-Number`.

You may use

```
/^([a-z])(\d+)([a-z])(\d+)$/i
```

and replace with `$1: $2-$3-$4`

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([a-z])` - Group 1 (referenced with `$1` from the replacement pattern) capturing any ASCII letter (as `/i` makes the pattern case-insensitive)
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 capturing 1 or more digits
- `([a-z])` - Group 3, a letter
- `(\d+)` - Group 4, a number (1 or more digits)
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zS9fQ7/1).

```js
var re = /^([a-z])(\d+)([a-z])(\d+)$/i; 
var s = 'y1e2';
var result = s.replace(re, '$1: $2-$3-$4');
console.log(result);
```

**OR** - if the letters must be turned to upper case:

```js
var re = /^([a-z])(\d+)([a-z])(\d+)$/i; 
var s = 'y1e2';
var result = s.replace(re, 
   (m,g1,g2,g3,g4)=>`${g1.toUpperCase()}: ${g2}-${g3.toUpperCase()}-${g4}`
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the function to match and replace the pattern: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/896aza38/3/)**

```
function findAndFormat(text){

  var splittedText=text.split(' ');

  for(var i=0, textLength=splittedText.length; i<textLength; i++){

    var analyzed=splittedText[i].match(/[A-z]{1}\d{1}[A-z]{1}\d{1}$/);

    if(analyzed){
        var formattedString=analyzed[0][0].toUpperCase()+': '+analyzed[0][1]+'-'+analyzed[0][2].toUpperCase()+'-'+analyzed[0][3];
            text=text.replace(splittedText[i],formattedString);
    }
  }
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think it's just as it reads:
y1e4

Letter, number, letter, number:

```
/([A-z][0-9][A-z][0-9])/g
```

And yes, it's ok to use regex in this case, like form validations and stuff like that. it's just there are some cases on which abusing of regular expressions gives you a bad performance (into intensive data processing and the like)

Example

```
"HelloY1E4world".replace(/([A-z][0-9][A-z][0-9])/g, ' ');
```

should return: "Hello world"

[regxr.com](http://www.regexr.com) always comes in handy

Comment: it must be the other way around, y1e4 formatting to Y: 1-E-4

Comment: Ok, borrowing from rccursach's example, it looks like my target pattern is: /(([A-Z]|[a-z])[0-9]([A-Z]|[a-z])[0-9])/g.  That's the search part, I'm sure the replace step is logical enough (using match() or replace() or split() etc).

Comment: yes, in fact you don't need to put [a-z][A-Z] but [A-z], answer edited again.

Comment: again your function removes the matched string, the OP wants to format it to Y: 1-E-4, not remove it

Comment: OP is asking what the regex is. at least that's what i can read in the Title.
The function is just to show that the regex works

Comment: "it's just there are some cases on which abusing of regular expressions gives you a bad performance (into intensive data processing and the like)" where did you get that from? regexp are super fast for string manipulations, if you know what you are doing with regexp, its always better to use them for "intensive data processing".

Comment: @AhmadBamieh, this is off topic. you may edit the answer if you like, but beware of the "always" word. "it's always better" is hard to probe. When i said that, you may imagine there are cases when custom algorithms in one domain will perform better than regex (like finding known patterns in very big text using custom dynamic programming algorithms, so i can tweak the trade between speed and accuracy ), but again, off topic.
The thing is it's ok to use them to validate a form input value.